# set background over the image on ImageView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

My gridView displays images (`imageItem`) from local storage with `Picasso`. Image's state is changed when it is selected by clicking the select icon in the top right conner, and on the selected state, the image has blue border like this: 
[image: blue border]

I tried something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!v.isSelected()){
                imageItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.photoborder);
            }else{
                imageItem.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

And I did see the border when the image has not been loaded.
When Picasso finishes loading image, the border has been covered:

[image: border has been covered]

How to set border over image in ImageView?
Thank you very much for any suggestion!!

Here is the layout for each image item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <custome.SquaredImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_item_in_gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@drawable/attachment_gallery_images_items_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCheckStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure since I don't use Picasso, but it seems that there are more than 1 layers used: `ImageView` as back layer and check mark indicator as front layer. What you are doing is setting the `ImageView`'s background, not the front layer. Perhaps it will be clearer if you could post the XML layout used in the adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout has 2 views; `SquaredImageView` to display the image, and `ImageView` as selection indicator. When you set the background for `SquaredImageView`, it will be placed behind `SquaredImageView` (as it is a background).

What you need is to add a `View` in front of `SquaredImageView`, then to modify its background in the code.

Add a `View` in your XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <custome.SquaredImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_item_in_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@drawable/attachment_gallery_images_items_background" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imageCheckBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/photoborder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCheckStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark" />

</FrameLayout >
```

Then modify the code to change the background of that `View`, instead of `SquaredImageView`. (in this example, it's named as `imageCheckBorder`)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!v.isSelected()){
        imageCheckBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.photoborder);
    }else{
        imageCheckBorder.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just also figured it out

Comment: Glad you figured it out by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use border drawable as layer for your imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/drawable_selector_border_thickness"
        android:color="#0099CC" />

    <solid android:color="#500099CC" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your code, you are using 2 different instances at the same time i.e.`imageItem.setBackgroundResource`
and

```
imageItem.setBackgroundDrawable
```

What you actually need to do is just simply stick with one of the background instances, and you would get your desired result. The code should look like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!v.isSelected()){
            imageItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.photoborder);
        }else{
            imageItem.setBackgroundResource(null);
        }
    }
});
```